# Where can I find low profile stopcock handles?

Tags: plumbing

I have a stopcock/isolation valve to the outdoor tap in the kitchen, it's located in a kitchen cupboard but unfortunately the distance between the shelf and the valve isn't big enough to turn the handle.

It's a lot like this one but I'm not 100% if it's exactly the same, it's brass with a similar style handle and has the screw in the middle.

[image: https://www.screwfix.com/p/poly-stop-cock-25mm-x-15mm/86048]

I was wondering if you can get replacement handles that are lower profile? I've tried googling low profile stopcock handle and not found any results, or if a low profile one doesn't exist can you get a sliding handle so you turn it half way, slide the bar to the other side and turn it again?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get a picture of the unit in situ. It's hard to tell from just the description quite how this doesn't fit & more importantly, what type of tap it is. The one pictured would seem to be a multi-revolution, that effectively screws up out of a sealed socket to open. Alternatives are simple 90° mechanisms. [Both answers so far seem to be assuming 90°]

Comment: I'll get one tonight, was at work when I wrote the question.  It is a multi-revolution type device hence the handle is bumping up against the shelf inside the cupboard.

Comment: OK. I guess the trick will be to swap to a 90° one then, as mentioned below, then you can get a bigger handle, better leverage, but only have to swing it 90° between fully on & off, so you can pick which 90° is easiest without it banging into the shelf.

Comment: That might not work out so well either, the picture will make it clearer but there is only a small hole to let the shaft through the back of the cupboard, replacing the whole valve will either involve cutting a big hole in the back of the cupboard or some very costly work removing a quartz worktop that I don't want to do.  Sorry for not putting a picture up in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more of your circumstances, some suggestions.

1. Remove the screw at the top and you can remove the handle and shift it.
2. Remove the handle, cut the shaft and put the handle back on.
3. Turn the tap sideways or upside down
4. Use a valve like this  [image: valve]

Answer (score 1):

If you undo the screw and remove the handle there will be a square end on the shaft,  turn it with a wrench or cut one end off the handle and use that as a wrench,

Alternatively you could cut a slot in the shelf to allow the handle to be turned.

Many kitchen cabinets have adjustable shelves. maybe you can lift or remove the shelf to make room to operate the valve.

Comment: The first part of this is very interesting, if I could use a wrench to turn it multiple times that woudl be great.  I will give this a go and if it works, mark this as the answer.  No cost which is even better.

Comment: Matt - see my comment above - you need to change the tap to do this, swinging a spanner 42 times to get the full open/closed cycle will be a nuisance.

Comment: If it is a small square end then I may have a socket I can put on a ratcheting screwdriver.  I'll take the picture and the end off the handle at the same time and see.

Comment: Let's hope the handle comes off. Mine doesn't. The ratchet spanner ought to be the one, in that case.

Comment: @Tetsujin there's a trade-off between disassembing the built-in furniture to replace the valve and the valve being hard to operate,.

Answer (score 0):

- Don't shop for a product like this online - you can't really get a feel for quality and size (dimensions may be measured in strange ways you don't expect) from pictures and descriptions on a web page. Not a problem for a straight replacement, big problem when you are trying to find something "different".
- Assuming you already tried your local big box (Home Depot, Lowes, etc.) and didn't find anything, your next stop is the local corner hardware store. If you still have one. I used to have two - one 2 blocks away from home, the other 2 blocks away from my office - both long gone. This is the kind of place where they know all the usual parts for the neighborhood homes, they save everything so they'll have parts that haven't sold in 20 years and know exactly where to find them in the seemingly incomprehensible piles, etc.
- And last, but definitely not least, find out where the plumbers go to get their parts. Many plumbers will now get many things at big box stores due to convenience and pricing, but they all have a place to go for the more unusual stuff, better pricing on a lot of the common stuff, special orders, etc. These places won't be in big shopping malls, but every city has them somewhere. They may charge a homeowner more than a regular plumber who comes in twice a week to stock their truck, but most will be happy to sell you the strange parts that you can't get at the big box stores.